# WYSWIG editor with autocomplete/hashtage replacement

Tags: autocomplete, ckeditor, str-replace, hashtag, summernote

I'm trying to implement tag-replacement/autocomplete functionality with usage of CKEditor or Summernote, but after a few days of smashing my head into the wall I haven't moved forward at all.
The problem:

- user types # in the editor which opens a autocomplete list, during typing list is filtered according to what is typed in
- when user selects one of the option the # with linked text is replaced with longer text
- user is able to continue writing without having to focus the editor after selecting the hashtag text

example:

> array( 
>   "welcometext" => "Dear user welcome in our system",
>   "footertext" => "Hope to here from you soon"
>   )

The two problems that I have with this are
- making any autocomplete to work in any way
- created simple ckeditor plugin that was replacing hastags with hardcoded text, but after replacement focus was lost

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this solution?

```
CKEDITOR.replace('fieldToReplace',{
  on: {
    'instanceReady': function(e){
      CKEDITOR.instances[fieldToReplace].focusManager.focus();
    }
});
```